# BERT Classifier ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([4, 1])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([4, 2]))

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I'm training a Classifier Model but it's a few days that I cannot overcame a problem!
I have the ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([4, 1])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([4, 2])) error but actually it seems correct to me ! Indeed I used unsqueeze(1) to put them of the same size. WHat else I can try? Thank you!

```
class SequenceClassifier(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, n_classes):
    super(SequenceClassifier, self).__init__()
    self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained(PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME,return_dict=False)
    self.drop = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)
    self.out = nn.Linear(self.bert.config.hidden_size, n_classes)
  
  def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
    _, pooled_output = self.bert(
      input_ids=input_ids,
      attention_mask=attention_mask
    ) 
    output = self.drop(pooled_output)
    return self.out(output)

model = SequenceClassifier(len(class_names))
model = model.to(device)

EPOCHS = 10

optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=2e-5, correct_bias=False)
total_steps = len(train_data_loader) * EPOCHS

scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(
  optimizer,
  num_warmup_steps=0,
  num_training_steps=total_steps
)
weights=[0.5,1]
pos_weight=torch.FloatTensor(weights).to(device)
loss_fn=nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight=pos_weight)

def train_epoch(
  model, 
  data_loader, 
  loss_fn, 
  optimizer, 
  device, 
  scheduler, 
  n_examples
):
  model = model.train()

  losses = []
  correct_predictions = 0
  
  for d in data_loader:
    input_ids = d["input_ids"].to(device)
    attention_mask = d["attention_mask"].to(device)
    targets = d["targets"].to(device)

    outputs = model(
      input_ids=input_ids,
      attention_mask=attention_mask
    )

    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
    
    targets = targets.unsqueeze(1)
    loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
    

    correct_predictions += torch.sum(preds == targets)
    losses.append(loss.item())

    loss.backward()
    nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)
    optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()

  return correct_predictions.double() / n_examples, np.mean(losses)
  

%%time

history = defaultdict(list)
best_accuracy = 0

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):

  print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{EPOCHS}')
  print('-' * 10)

  train_acc, train_loss = train_epoch(
    model,
    train_data_loader,    
    loss_fn, 
    optimizer, 
    device, 
    scheduler, 
    len(df_train)
  )

  print(f'Train loss {train_loss} accuracy {train_acc}')

  val_acc, val_loss = eval_model(
    model,
    val_data_loader,
    loss_fn, 
    device, 
    len(df_val)
  )

  print(f'Val   loss {val_loss} accuracy {val_acc}')
  print()

  history['train_acc'].append(train_acc)
  history['train_loss'].append(train_loss)
  history['val_acc'].append(val_acc)
  history['val_loss'].append(val_loss)

  if val_acc > best_accuracy:
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'best_model_state.bin')
    best_accuracy = val_acc
```

```
ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([4, 1])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([4, 2]))
```

**EDIT**
I have a binary classifier problem, indeed i have 2 classes encoded 0 ("bad") and 1 ("good").

Comment: try `target.unsqueeze(1)' the target by 1 to change the the size of the input size

Comment: Thank you but if you see i already tried in my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles on this like I did, I'll write out an answer since there aren't a lot of google hits for this target size/input size error and the previous answer has some factual inaccuracies.

Unlike the previous answer would suggest, the real problem isn't with the loss function but with the output of the model.`nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss` is completely fine for multi-label and multi-class applications. Chiara updated her post saying that in fact she has a binary classification problem, but even that should not be a problem for this loss function. So why the error?

The original code has:

```
outputs = model(
  input_ids=input_ids,
  attention_mask=attention_mask
)
_, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
```

This means "Run the model, then create `preds` with the row indeces of the highest output of the model". Obviously, there is only a "index of highest" if there are multiple  predicted values. Multiple output values usually means multiple input classes, so I can see why Shai though this was multi-class. But why would we get multiple outputs from a binary classifier?

As it turns out, BERT (or Huggingface anyway) for binary problems expects that `n_classes` is set to 2 -- setting classes to 1 puts the model in regression mode. This means that under the hood, binary problems are treated like a two-class problem, outputting predictions with the size [2, *batch size*] -- one column predicting the chance of it being a 1 and one for the chance of it being 0. The loss fucntion throws an error because it is supplied with only one row of one-hot encoded labels: `targets = d["targets"].to(device)` so the  labels have dimensions [*batch size*] or after the unsqueeze, [1, *batch size*]. Either way, the dimensions don't match up.

Some loss functions can deal with this fine, but others require the exact same dimensions. To make things more frustrating, for version 1.10, `nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss` requires matching dimensions but later versions do not.

One solution may therefore be to update your pytorch (version 1.11 would work for example).

For me, this was not an option, so I ended up going with a different loss function. `nn.CrossEntropyLoss`, as suggested by Shai, indeed does the trick as it accepts any input with the same length. In other words, they had a working solution for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) loss function. This loss function works for *binary* classification tasks, and expects the predictions and the targets to be of the same shape (and `float` data type).
This is in contrast to the multi-class CE loss function [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) that expects the targets to be *integers* pointing to the proper place in the predicted class probabilities.

Please read *carefully* the doc of the functions you are using and make sure you are using them correctly.

Comment: thank you for the explanation but I'm using it with a binary classification problem. I have 2 classes, labeled 0 and 1.

Comment: @Chiara therefore, you should have converted your `targets` from 1d indices of the right class (0 or 1) to float tensors of the same size of the output. Read the doc on these two loss functions and see the difference in the way they expect their `targets` to be. Currently, you are using the binary loss, but your `targets` are in the format of multi-class CE loss.

Comment: thank you but this is way I used unsqueeze. sorry i'm new using pytorch. I'm trying to understand where I have to do the editing